# Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: mocking, mockito

```
Wanted but not invoked:
provider.startAudit(
    "cn=dlakshman,cn=organizational users,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=Audit,o=vanenburg.com",
    "XMLS tore",
    "/Cordys/Test/test.log",
    "UpdateXMLObject",
    "o=system,cn=cordys,cn=Audit,o=vanenburg.com",
    "Add",
    "input",
    Cordys.XMLStore.Messages.xmlstoreUpdateEntryStart, 
 ""
);->



at com.cordys.XMLStoreAudit.MockXMLStoreAuditTest.verifyUpdate(MockXMLStoreAuditTest.java:146)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.cordys.XMLStoreAudit.MockXMLStoreAuditTest.verifyUpdate(MockXMLStoreAuditTest.java:146)
    at com.cordys.XMLStoreAudit.MockXMLStoreAuditTest.testAuditXMLStoreCreate(MockXMLStoreAuditTest.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

please help me with above problem:

my source looks like:

```
{@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockXMLStoreAuditTest
{
    private static final String     XMLSTORE_ARTIFACT_TYPE  = "XMLS tore";

    private static final String     USER_DN                 = "cn=dlakshman,cn=organizational users,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=Audit,o=vanenburg.com";

    private static final String     DESCRIPTION             = "UpdateXMLObject";

    private static final String     ORG_DN                  = "o=system,cn=cordys,cn=Audit,o=vanenburg.com";

    public @Rule
    SystemPropertySetter            propertiesSetter        = new SystemPropertySetter();

    @Mock
    AuditProvider                   provider;
    @Mock
    AuditRecording                  recording;

    private Connector connector;
    @Before
    public void setAuditInspector() throws ExceptionGroup, DirectoryException
    {
        propertiesSetter.setValue(Audit.AUDITPROVIDER_PROPERTY_NAME, TestAuditProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
        TestAuditProvider.auditProvider = provider;

        when(provider.isAuditEnabled(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);
        when(provider.startAudit(anyString(),
                                isA(String.class),
                                isA(String.class),
                                isA(String.class),
                                isA(String.class),
                                isA(String.class),
                                anyString(),
                                isA(IStringResource.class),
                                anyVararg())).thenReturn(recording);

        connector = Connector.getInstance("XMLStore");
        if(!connector.isOpen())
        {
            connector.open();
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testAuditXMLStoreCreate () throws Exception
    {
        updateXMLObject("Add");
        verifyUpdate("Add");
    }


    private void updateXMLObject ( String operation ) throws DirectoryException, XMLException, TimeoutException,
            ExceptionGroup, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        int request = 0;
        int response = 0;
        try
        {
            request = connector.createSOAPMethod("http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/xmlstore", "UpdateXMLObject");
            Node.appendToChildren(XPath.getFirstMatch(".//" + operation + "/tuple", null,NomUtil.readResourceAsNom(getClass(), "UpdateXMLRequests.xml")), request);
            response = connector.sendAndWait(request);
        }
        finally
        {
            Node.delete(request);
            Node.delete(response);
        }
    }

        private void verifyUpdate (String actionType)
        {
            verify(provider).startAudit(USER_DN,
                                        XMLSTORE_ARTIFACT_TYPE,
                                        "/Cordys/Test/test.log",
                                        DESCRIPTION,
                                        ORG_DN,
                                        actionType,
                                        "input",
                                        Messages.XMLSTORE_UPDATE_ENTRY_START,
                                        "");
            verify(recording).completed(AuditStatus.COMPLETE, Messages.XMLSTORE_AUDIT_ENTRY_COMPLETE, anyString());
            verify(provider).isAuditEnabled(ORG_DN, XMLSTORE_ARTIFACT_TYPE);

        }



}
```

The call to following will call startAudit() method internally.

> response = connector.sendAndWait(request);

I think it is not calling the mocked startAudit() instead it is calling actual startAudit().

I

Comment: Have you verified that the connector actually uses the TestAuditProvider? This is the reason that people dislike system-wide singleton kind of style. Using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) will clean up this code. You can then directly inject your mocked AuditProvider into the connector.

Comment: In this case connector is **not using TestAuditProvider**, It is **using actual AuditProvider**. That is what my concern is. **How to make connector to use TestAuditProvider?**. How can I **directly inject** my mocked AuditProvider into the connector?

Comment: The actual call to startAudit() is in some method say **UpdateXMLObject** class. After call to **connector.sendAndWait(request)** , there happens to call so many internal classes, methods  and **finally** reach **UpdateXMLObject**.  Also there is a abstarct class **XDSBasedXMLStore** which is extended by **UpdateXMLObject**. Again there is utility class **XMLStoreAuditManager** whose object is aggregated in **XDSBasedXMLStore** abstract class. So that all classes who extend **XDSBasedXMLStore** will have **XMLStoreAuditManager** object and call startAudit() method.

Comment: This is my scenario. When control comes to **startAudit()** in **UpdateXMLObject**  the **TestAuditProvider** should be called which is not happening for me.

Comment: We can not see how the Connector obtains a reference to the AuditProvider. Please share the relevant pieces of code so we can be of further assistance.

Comment: Injection Has worked for me. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636980/play-framework-java-mock-using-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there Can anyone help solve this?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I directly inject mocked AuditProvider into the connector it works fine. Thanks all.

Comment: Please can you share the code the fixed your problem?